# Terminating jq processing when condition is met

Tags: jq

I am using jq to search for specific results in a large file. I do not care for duplicate entries matching this specific condition, and it takes a while to process the whole file. What I would like to do is print some details about the first match and then terminate the jq command on the file to save time.

I.e.

```
jq '. | if ... then "print something; exit jq" else ... end'
```

I looked into http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/?#Breakingoutofcontrolstructures but this didn't quite seem to apply

EDIT:
The file I am parsing contains multiple json objects, one after another. They are not in an array.

Comment: Is your large file a single json value (e.g., an array) or multiple values (objects one after the other)?

Comment: Could you provide a more specific example of the data you have and how you intend to process it?

Comment: As Jeff said, it would be great if you provided some data sample. This is especially important considering that your use case probably requires using the `--stream` flag, which changes the rules substantially and makes basic `jq` operations incredibly complex.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach which uses a recent version of `first/1` (currently in  master)

```
def first(g): label $out | g | ., break $out; 

first(inputs | if .=="100" then . else empty end)
```

Example:

```
$ seq 1000000000 | jq -M -Rn -f filter.jq
```

Output (followed by immediate termination)

```
"100"
```

Here I use `seq` in lieu of a large JSON dataset.

Answer (score 3):

To do what is requested is possible using features that were added after the release of jq 1.4.  The following uses *foreach* and *inputs*:

```
label $top
| foreach inputs as $line
   # state: true means found; false means not yet found
   (false;
    if . then break $top
    else if $line | tostring | test("goodbye") then true else false end
    end;
    if . then $line else empty end
   )
```

Example:

```
$ cat << EOF | jq -n -f exit.jq
1
"goodbye"
3
4
EOF
```

Result:
    "goodbye"

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish it using [`halt`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#halt) and the [`inputs`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#inputs) builtin:

```
jq -n 'inputs | if ... then "something", halt else ... end'
```

Will print `"something"` and terminate gracefully when the condition matches.

For this to work (i.e. terminate when condition is true), `jq` needs the `-n` parameter. See this [issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/2368)